# Last pinball machine for The Children of Violent Rome (1976), a little difficult recognize

Tags: game-identification, pinball

This pinball machine appear in movie The Children of Violent Rome (1976), is a little difficult to recognize because the image is not clear, I capture three scenes, hope it help.

[image: scene 1]

[image: scene 2]

[image: scene3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recognized!
It's "Sky Jump" from Gottlieb(or a similar flipper with another title released for Italy).

The first image is actually from another Gottlieb flipper called "Psychedelic" and is an editing error of the movie! If you see the entire movie you can see the same image in a scene at minute 5!